# Peeling very ripe plantains?

Tags: peeling

I'm following the "slit & peel" advice,  but I'm not getting consistant results.

Sometimes,  my ripe plantain (90% black)  has a peel that is impossibly hard to remove -  it's dry and sticks to a very soft flesh. I end up throwing most of it away -  even though the bits I mange to save are sweet and tasty.

Have I stored it incorrectly?

It would appear that I have no trouble peeling 50% black plantains, but as they get closer to full black (max sweetness), they tend to dry up and the peel sticks.

Answer (score 1):

I will often freeze black bananas that are too soft to peel, then thaw or run warm water over them till I can remove the peel from the still frozen fruit.

Answer (score 0):

where I live a black plantain isn't often so mature on the inside that the peel sticks. when it does, you are tempted to put down the knife and do it by hand, and it clearly is the wrong thing to do. The advice I would give is "don't put down the knife". In fact, if you have to, split the plantain lengthwise before removing the skin once you realize that it is a sticky situation.

Answer (score 0):

If the peel is dry and lacks structural integrity to pull cleanly off the flesh, I would try slicing it off with a knife.  If the flesh is not too mushy, you could use a vegetable peeler, but you said yours was very soft, so a more gentle approach would be to use a knife, just like you might to peel an apple with a knife.